# Alternative Cloud Hashing sites to Cex.io

Tags: mining-pools, hash, cloud-mining

I am really impressed with Cex.io and their whole concept of trading Ghs for Bitcoin as well as cloud mining which I find to be novel and interesting.

Are there any other sites like that? I know there are a number of cloud hashing sites but what I am looking for is one similar to Cex where I can also do commodity trading.

Comment: so basically, no is the answer cause those are nothing like cex

Comment: I guess so iam still waiting for an answer

Comment: lol why is this off topic??? If it is offtopic where do I ask this???

Comment: Hi Ram and welcome! The text below explains why it was considered off topic ("product or service recommendations" usually are).

Comment: Ok so where do I ask it because I am really interested in an alternative? Don't want to put all my eggs in one basket if you see what I mean. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

[Cloudhashing.com](http://cloudhashing.com) does cloud mining, but they did not offer trading the last time I checked.

Comment: I know about cloudhashing it is now what I am looking for beside it is very expensive

Answer (score 1):

You can buy some shares in the 500TH-mine project: https://picostocks.com/stocks/view/19

The price is much lower than at cex.io currently (cex.io - 0.0604, 500TH - 0.04)

Answer (score 1):

Australian business called BitMiners - http://www.bitminers.com.au - Appear to be fairly established as they are a division of a larger company. cheapest and most "credible" i can find.

Answer (score 0):

A alternative to both Cloudhashing.com and cex.io is Butterfly labs, currently at the price they are offering at butterfly labs is cheaper than both cex.io and Cloudhashing.  However it is a preorder, I think they will be launching in Feburary.

[Butterfly Labs Cloud Hashing, $10.83/GHS](http://cur.lv/5dlmz)